# Is there an `appsettings.json` configuration file at the machine level and user levels?

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration

I know that, for a desktop application, the old `*.config` mechanism had four levels of configuration files:

- `machine.config` - in the .net install directory
- `app.config` - in the application's directory
- `user.config` - in the user's roaming directory
- `user.config` - in the user's local directory

What is the equivalence of those files in the new system, the one that uses JSON files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do all this granularly with the `ConfigurationBuilder`, it has the flexibility to do all those concerns and more by just adding the known configuration files in the right order. The downside is it's a little more verbose. However, write yourself an extension method if you want:

<sub>***Note** : If you are using asp.netcore you get access to the `IConfigurationRoot` in the configuration methods E.g `ConfigureAppConfiguration`, ergo you don't need to instantiate a new `ConfigurationBuilder` as shown below.*</sub>

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
   .SetBasePath(...)
   // some machine config
   .AddJsonFile(@"<The path to your globalSettings>\appsettings.json", optional: true) 
   // Your main app settings
   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
   // environment specific
   .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
   // Machine specific
   .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.MachineName}.json", optional: true)
    // user specific
   .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile),"Your App Name","appsettings.json"), optional: true)
   .AddEnvironmentVariables()
   ...
```

<sub>***Disclaimer** : The following is not meant to be the greatest code in the world, it's just a tribute. You will need to do whatever it is that makes sense to you and your environment.*</sub>

**The longer story:**

The `IConfigurationRoot` is just a collection of providers and sources. The providers collapse to a collection of key value pairs. Each subsequent provider you add has the ability to override the previous providers values if available, and roughly 1000 times better than the old `app.config`/`web.config` paradigm.